# Como criar tabelas em Postgre com campos not null?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

bom dia senhores,

Fiz minha tentativa de criar minha tabela Postgre dessa forma:

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
    codigo BIGSERIAL,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(codigo)
);
```

Apesar do campo **nome** estar como **not null** ele está permitindo que seja inserido null como podem ver abaixo;

Imagem 1º

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

prova da inserção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

descrição do campo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que ficou faltando alguma coisa na construção da tabela para ele efetivar o **not null** no campo **nome**?

Comment: Não temos como saber, está afirmando que não funciona e mostrando nada que informe isto, quando, porque, de que forma acontece.

Comment: acabo de executar o mesmo comando aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Ambas colunas como not null

Comment: Desculpe pela minha postagem, acabei de corrigir, @Maniero poderia dá uma olhada agora por favor?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis existe alguma verificação que posso fazer para analisa porque isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema, fiz o que você fez e retornou erro: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/947d4/1

Comment: Tente: `INSERT INTO categoria (codigo) values (7);` para verificar se ainda assim haverá a inserção.

Comment: não houve = ERROR:  null value in column "nome" violates not-null constraint

por favor sabe me explicar o que está acontecendo?

Comment: nossa que estranho @Maniero